# How to setup a base URL and where do I declare it in flutter dio for api calls?

Tags: api, flutter, dart, dio

**like how to fix boilerplate code in separate file and use it in ui pages.**

> **I Need to declare this uri variable in separate file and access across over all pages:**

```
  static var uri = "https://xxx/xxx/web_api/public";
  static BaseOptions options = BaseOptions(
  baseUrl: uri,
  responseType: ResponseType.plain,
  connectTimeout: 30000,
  receiveTimeout: 30000,
  // ignore: missing_return
  validateStatus: (code) {
    if (code >= 200) {
      return true;
    }
  });  static Dio dio = Dio(options);
```

**In UI page i have to declare that uri variable and BaseOption variable in this future function:**

```
   Future<dynamic> _loginUser(String email, String password) async {
     try {
  Options options = Options(
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
  );
  Response response = await dio.post('/login',
      data: {
        "email": email,
        "password": password,
        "user_type": 2,
        "status": 1
      },
      options: options);

  if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
    var responseJson = json.decode(response.data);
    return responseJson;
  } else if (response.statusCode == 401) {
    throw Exception("Incorrect Email/Password");
  } else
    throw Exception('Authentication Error');
} on DioError catch (exception) {
  if (exception == null ||
      exception.toString().contains('SocketException')) {
    throw Exception("Network Error");
  } else if (exception.type == DioErrorType.RECEIVE_TIMEOUT ||
      exception.type == DioErrorType.CONNECT_TIMEOUT) {
    throw Exception(
        "Could'nt connect, please ensure you have a stable network.");
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

}

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. The base url seems to be setup correctly `baseUrl: uri,`. You can then use a `FutureBuilder` widget to use `_loginUser` after you make it public (assuming it's in a different file) by renaming to to `loginUser`.

Comment: the base url boilerplate code need to be in separate page not in a same page and from that class uri and option variables passed across all pages that uses apis:like

Comment: Response response = await dio.post('Uri+/login',
      data: {
        "email": email,
        "password": password,
        "user_type": 2,
        "status": 1
      },
      options: options);@Er1

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23522407/how-to-setup-a-base-url-and-where-do-i-declare-it)

Comment: Please accept the below answer if it's useful for you. So, we can save the time of others :) @SanjeeviRaj

Answer (score 9):

You can create app_config.dart file and manage different environments like below:

```
const _baseUrl = "baseUrl";

enum Environment { dev, stage, prod }

Map<String, dynamic> _config;

void setEnvironment(Environment env) {
  switch (env) {
    case Environment.dev:
      _config = devConstants;
      break;
    case Environment.stage:
      _config = stageConstants;
      break;
    case Environment.prod:
      _config = prodConstants;
      break;
  }
}

dynamic get apiBaseUrl {
  return _config[_baseUrl];
}

Map<String, dynamic> devConstants = {
  _baseUrl: "https://devapi.xyz.com/",
};


Map<String, dynamic> stageConstants = {
  _baseUrl: "https://api.stage.com/",
};

Map<String, dynamic> prodConstants = {
  _baseUrl: "https://api.production.com/",
};
```

Comment: How would you call setEnvironment?

Comment: @WilliamChou We are having 3 environments: development, stage, production. We have 3 dart files which sets the current environment based on flavours. 1) main_dev.dart, 2) main_stage.dart, 3) main_prod.dart. So, based on selected flavour, we will set the environment in the dart file.

Comment: @WilliamChou Let me know if you require any help.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe instead of statically declaring your `Dio` object you could put it in a class, also put your `loginUser` function in there, and use `Provider` to obtain that object to call it where you need it.

```dart
class Api {
  static var uri = "https://xxx/xxx/web_api/public";
  static BaseOptions options = BaseOptions(
  baseUrl: uri,
  responseType: ResponseType.plain,
  connectTimeout: 30000,
  receiveTimeout: 30000,
  // ignore: missing_return
  validateStatus: (code) {
    if (code >= 200) {
      return true;
    }
  }); 
  Dio dio = Dio(options);

  Future<dynamic> loginUser(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      RequestOptions options = RequestOptions(
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
      );
    Response response = await dio.post('/login',
        data: {
          "email": email,
          "password": password,
          "user_type": 2,
          "status": 1
        },
        options: options);
    //the rest of your code here
}
```

https://pub.dev/packages/provider

```dart
Provider(
  create: (_) => Api(),
  child: ...
)
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

```dart
YourWidget(
  child: Consumer<Api>(
    builder: (context, api, child) {
      return FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
      future: api.loginUser('mail@mail.com', 'user_password')
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          //show a widget based on snapshot.data
        } else {
          //show another widget
        }
      }
    },
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I set domain and env values in `.env` file. Then I read it using [dotenv pacckage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dotenv)

**local.env**

```
env=local
apidomain=localhost:8000
```

**dev.env**

```
env=dev
apidomain=xyz.com
```

Following function gives url (http or https) based on environment. It uses domain based on environment too

```
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';

Uri getCompleteUrl({required String url}) {
  // if local env then http else https url
  String domain = dotenv.get('apidomain'); // localhost:8000 or xyz.com
  if (dotenv.get('env') == 'local') {
    return Uri.http(domain, url);
  } else {
    return Uri.https(domain, url);
  }
}
```